# itertools islice not able to select multiple lines?

Tags: python, python-itertools

I have the following loop:

```
i = 0
with open(decrypted_file, "r") as text_file:
    while len(introduction_point) < 3:
        for line in itertools.islice(text_file, i, i+1):
            introduction_point.append(str.split(''.join(line))[1])
            i = i + 15
text_file.close()
```

what I am trying to do is select line 1, 16, and 31 and add the data on these lines to an array list, however it gets stuck on the second round where `i = 15` on the line

```
for line in itertools.islice(text_file, i, i+1):
```

How can I use `islice` for this purpose, or do I have to close the file ad reopen it each time as this seems although works fine a waste of resources.

Comment: You should not close `text_file` manually, the `with` statement is made for.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot do what you want by incrementing `i`, no. The `islice()` object is created just *once*, and `i` is not consulted after that. Adding to the `i` integer is not ever going to change what lines the loop will process.

You need to use a step size instead:

```
for line in itertools.islice(text_file, 0, 31, 15):
```

Now the first line, the 16th line and the 31st line are used, as the `islice()` steps through the lines 15 at a time.

Note that the `text_file.close()` line is entirely redundant, the `with` statement has already signalled to the  file by that time that the block is done, and the file is *already* closed.

If you need a different set of lines that are *not* so regularly spaced, don't use `islice()`; use `enumerate()` and test if the line number matches:

```
for lineno, line in enumerate(text_file):
    if lineno not in {0, 15, 17, 31, 45}:
        # not a line we are interested in, skip
        continue
    # rest of your loop
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, that a great understandable answer, one last quick question, is it possible, depending on what line is select to update a different variable, such as for line 31 update x while line 0, 15 update y

Comment: @user2061913: then use `enumerate()` still; for `islice()` that means you get indices 0, 1, 2 though. You can then do `if lineno == something` to alter what you want to do.

Comment: Should be something like `itertools.islice(text_file, 0, 31+1, 15)` as stop parameter is not inclusive.

Comment: Indices 0, 15 and 30 are picked; the OP is using 1-based indexing in places. As such 31 is fine as the end value.